# Oracle timestamp column dropping fractions of seconds

Tags: oracle, timestamp

We are testing one of our test Oracle databases upgraded from 12.1 to 12.2 and have come across a fairly serious problem.

Some of our tables include columns of type timestamp with time zone. At the time of the upgrade these contain values that can and do include fractions of seconds.

What we have noticed is that any routine that now (under 12.2) tries to populate data in such columns results in the fractional seconds value being truncated and the value being rounded to the nearest second. It is almost as if we are attempting to insert a timestamp into a date field.

E.g. if we try and insert the value '01-JAN-2017 12:34:56.789' into a TTZ column in the 12.2 instance, the value that gets inserted is actually '01-JAN-2017 12:34:57.000'.

What's worse is that this data loss is occurring silently, with no warning given.

Anyone else had this?

Comment: What is the precision of the timestamp column? And were there pre-upgrade values in the table that still exist now, and if so have they kept their original precision? Is the TZ being preserved properly - if you try with different TZs? (Presumably you'd know if you had a trigger doing this, or were bouncing through a date datatype somewhere on the way).

Comment: Precision is 6, although the source data tends to specify only 3 places. Hard to say if pre-upgrade values are being kept as so far I have only seen the issue in staging tables where all the data is transient. I believe the timezone is being stored correctly.

Comment: You said you saw the problem on insert; does that mean actual `insert` statements, run natively through a client (particularly SQL\*Plus), or run through say JDBC or OCI, or via a tool of some kind? Or some other mechanism, like `impdp` or SQL\*Loader or external tables? If the data is transient is it only happening with global temporary tables, or are they standard permanent tables? Just trying to narrow it down a bit...

Comment: Problem has been replicated by running straight insert...values... via sqldeveloper and sqlplus. Also with inserts...select ... from <external table>. Inserts into standard heap tables which are usually truncated then populated once per etl execution.

Comment: If you can create a small standalone [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from table creation to query that would be useful. But if you can then you may need to raise a service request with Oracle. I haven't heard of anything like this, and a quick browse of MOS doesn't throw up anything obvious. Good luck.